# Which wavelength is most likely to be emitted over the lifetime of a black hole by hawking radiation and which is most likely at any given time?

Tags: black-hole, hawking-radiation, quantum-mechanics

What equations tells us the most likely wavelength emitted for a given black hole mass at any instant in time and over the whole life of the black hole?

Comment: See Viktor Toth's [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator)

Comment: Great link. I used it to find that a WIMP particle of mass 10^-25 kg could be the peak emission of a black hole of mass 10^12 kg which would have a starting temperature of 3 K.

Comment: @PM2Ring Nice... A 1E11 kg black hole would provide around 36GW of power and only require a steady influx of new matter to maintain its size.

Comment: @Michael Sure, but the peak wavelength is 415 MeV gamma rays, which isn't a very convenient form of energy, and you need to fight that gamma ray flux to feed 396 micrograms / second of matter to an event horizon that's smaller than a proton.

Answer (score 7):

A black hole is black... and is a nearly perfect black-body radiator.  It emits across the whole range of wavelengths, but the peak wavelength is given by Wien's law

$$\lambda_* = 2.898×10^{-3} / T$$

Where temperature is in Kelvin.

The effective temperature of a black hole is

$$T = \frac{\hbar c^3}{8 \pi G M k_\mathrm{B}}$$

In which $\hbar$, $c$, $G$ and $k_\mathrm{B}=1.38×10^{-23}$ are Planck's constant, the speed of light, the gravitational constant, and boltzmann's constant, and $M$ is the mass of the black hole.

From these you can find that a stellar mass black hole has a temperature well below the temperature of the cosmic microwave background, so any stellar mass black hole will be gaining more mass (from the cosmic background even if nothing else) than it is losing in Hawking radiation.

Comment: In the early universe perhaps small black holes gave out more energy than they received from the CMB.

Comment: If black holes emitted dark matter would  the most common dark matter particles obey Weins law too.

Comment: Stellar mass black holes aren't mentioned in the Q. Whether they absorb more than they emit does not change what they emit.

Comment: No, that's just some background context.

Comment: Looks like[$$T_{\text{1 solar mass}}\approx 6.17 \cdot {10}^{-8} \mathrm{K}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28hbar+*+c%5E3%29+%2F+%288+*+pi+*+G+*+k_B%29+%2F+%281+solar+mass%29).